# Typescript - Dynamically type useForm for react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form with typescript and have the code like below. Is there any way to dynamically set type to react-hook-form `useForm<DynamicType>()` based on the value of categories props or at least not to repeat code like I am doing now?

What I want to achieve:

```
type DynamicType = Background | Project

if (category === 'background') {
  return DynamicType as Background
} return DynamicType as Project

const form = useForm<DynamicType>()
```

My current code:

```js
import React from 'react';

import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

import type { Background } from '../../../../types/Background';
import type { Project } from '../../../../types/Projects';
import {
  useBackgroundMutation,
  useQueryBackground,
} from '../../../../utils/background';
import {
  projectFormDefaultValues,
  backgroundFormDefaultValues,
} from '../../../../utils/data';
import { getAsString } from '../../../../utils/helper';
import {
  useProjectsMutation,
  useQueryProjects,
} from '../../../../utils/projects';
import HookForm from './HookForm';

type Props = {
  category: string;
};

const FormTemplate: React.VFC<Props> = (props) => {
  const { category } = props;
  const router = useRouter();
  const id = getAsString(router.query.id!);

  const queryBackground = useQueryBackground(id);
  const queryProject = useQueryProjects(id);

  const backgroundForm = useForm<Background>();
  const projectForm = useForm<Project>();

  const backgroundFormReset = backgroundForm.reset;
  const projectFormReset = projectForm.reset;

  const projectsMutation = useProjectsMutation(
    projectFormReset,
    projectFormDefaultValues
  );
  const backgroundMutation = useBackgroundMutation(
    backgroundFormReset,
    backgroundFormDefaultValues
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <HookForm
        category={category}
        categories={}
        query={category === 'background' ? queryBackground : queryProject}
        form={category === 'background' ? backgroundForm : projectForm}
        mutateFunction={
          category === 'background' ? backgroundMutation : projectsMutation
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default FormTemplate;
```

Comment: can you post your answer if you found the solution? I am also facing the same issue